# Can I use epoxy paint over latex paint on a bathtub and shower walls?

Tags: bathroom

The bathtub and shower surround is in a manufactured home and I am assuming that it is made of fiberglass. The previous owner painted the surfaces with regular latex paint. I know it will not hold up and need to fix it. Can I use epoxy paint over it or does the latex paint need to be removed first? The trim and walls have the same latex paint on them.

Comment: The epoxy will only stick to whatever is immediately beneath it - so epoxying over latex paint is a waste of good epoxy, since we know the latex is just going to peel off

Comment: That's the gist of it. When a layer is poorly adhering *because of poor prep*, there is no "magic bullet" that will spare you the work of hand-stripping it all off.  Fortunately the weaker range of strippers will curdle latex without perturbing the gelcoat layer beneath it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Very helpful